# If key is not defined then variable name is taken as key in javascript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Let's consider the following example

```
a = [1,2]
c = {a, b: "Hello"}
```

Output in chrome dev tool

```
{
  "a": [
    1,
    2
  ],
  "b": "Hello"
}
```

How this is happening is it safe to create a object like this?

Comment: It is really difficult to understand what your question is. Can you think of a way to re-word it to make it more clear?

Comment: The key is never evaluated as a variable, it's always a literal. So it doesn't matter if it's defined.

Comment: this demonstrates [ES2015 shorthand property name notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) - is it safe? no, because internet explorer, that's why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an object literal, there are two ways to enter elements.

The traditional way is `key: value`. In this case, `key` is not evaluated, it's taken as a literal, while `value` is evaluated. So in your `b: "Hello"` element, it doesn't matter whether `b` is defined, it always creates the key `"b"`.

EcmaScript 6 added a shorthand notation, where you just put one variable, like your `a` element. This is short for `a: a`, so it uses the name of the variable as the key, and then uses its value as the value. In this case, the variable does need to be defined.

There are some other shorthands for creating properties with functions, see [Enhanced Object Literals](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals).

As for whether it's safe, see the compatibility table in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) (which also goes into more detail about each of these shorthand notations).

Comment: you forgot to answer "is it safe"

Comment: @barmar Thanks for the great explanation